# How can show value through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to show a phone number when customer contact has it

Table:

```
|customers|
  |id|  |name|
   1    Zidane
   2    Mourinho
   3    Guardiola
   4    Ferguson

|contacts|
  |id|  |customer_id| |name|          |phone|
    1         1        Muller    
    2         1        Alaba          9872147  
    3         2        Aubameyang     2323234
    4         3        Dante   
    5         3        Robben    
    6         3        Lewandoski     2343256
    7         4        Ribery
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @customers = Customer.all
end
```

Model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

View:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <%= customer.name %>
  <% customer.contacts(:conditions=>['phone>0']).each do |contact| %>
    <%= contact.name %>
    <%= contact.phone %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also tried:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <%= customer.name %>
  <% customer.contacts.each do |contact| %>
    <%= contact.name %>
    <%= contact.phone(:all,:conditions=>['phone>0']). %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also tried but is only getting the first contact:

```
<%= customer.contacts.first(1).map { |c| c.phone } %>
```

Also tried but is only getting the last contact:

```
<%= customer.contacts.last(1).map { |c| c.phone } %>
```

I want this as result:

```
|customer|  |name_contact| |phone|
Zidane        Alaba         9872147
CR7           Aubameyang    2323234
Guardiola     Lewandoski    2343256
Ferguson      Ribery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below can work

```
<% customer.contacts.all {|c| c.phone.present?}.each do |contact| %>
```

Full snippet

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <%= customer.name %>
  <% customer.contacts.all {|c| c.phone.present?}.each do |contact| %>
    <%= contact.name %>
    <%= contact.phone %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I assume rest of the code will remain same, I just suggested change to iterator part

Comment: Even without using `all`, it should have worked.  I have tried locally in rails console - `customer.contacts` will give you all contacts of a customer.  Using `all` makes a DB query - which may not be needed.